# How does this function keep track of clicks?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

On the ["Thinking in Compose" page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) I don't get this code, how does $clicks keep track of number of clicks?

```
@Composable
fun ClickCounter(clicks: Int, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = onClick) {
        Text("I've been clicked $clicks times")
    }
}
```

I'm learning Kotlin at the same time as Compose, so I get puzzled all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's omitted in that example but it should store the click-count in a `MutableState<T>` wrapped with `remember`

```
var clickCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0)}

ClickCounter(clicks = clickCount, onClick = {clickCount += it})
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "{clickCount += it}"?

Comment: You are right. I missed that it doesn't increase clickCount inside `ClickCounter` body

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't. The click coming sound be inside a viewModel, not a composable scope since it's prone to destruction and resetting. That's the case when it is the sole purpose of the demo, hence it is an important piece of data. Practically, timers aren't usually mainframe, so it's fine to do a little dirty hack. Still, even in that scenario, risks can arise and the variable is still the safest placed within a lifecycle aware viewModel.

Comment: Who's going to upvote **my** comment?

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper here you have my upvote. :) You are right, but it can be both but point of this question is not having a means to store value and trigger recomposition. They should update official docs to not confuse people i guess

Comment: I just realised some typos. In the second line of the comment, it should be "The click *count should* be inside a viewModel", just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

For real real real beginner like me, let me add my comment and code.
When the ClickCounter composable is called we need to pass two parameters.

1. To 'clicks', we pass initial value 0 which will be changed everytime we click the button. Also the initial value need to be 'remembered' and tracked for further changes. So we create new variable using 'mutableStateOf' function inside 'remember' function.
2. To 'onClick', we need to pass function which adds 1 everytime the button is clicked.

As a caller of the ClickCounter composable, I made a simple preview composable as below.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ClickCounterPreview(){
    var clicks by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    // We call ClickCounter composable passing two parameters.
    ClickCounter(clicks = clicks, onClick = { clicks += 1 })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was agonising with the same doc, there are 2 errors in there because of which the text and code does not make any sense.

1. The doc says "Recomposition is the process of calling your composable functions again when **inputs** change. This happens when the **function's inputs** change. When Compose recomposes based on **new inputs**, it only calls the functions or lambdas that might have changed, and **skips the rest**."
   **Wrong!** Put log statements into composables and you will see that also the calling composable gets run again on recomposition. That is the actual reason why an Int variable gets reset and the code does not work. To be sure there was no other unmentioned quirk involved, I added also wrapper calls around the call to ClickCounter and logged also their runs, which confirmed my result.
2. Because of (1) the code does not work the way the text promises, and you need to add code and use the remember API so that the variable would not get reset on recomposition,

var clicks by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

The code in the doc by itself is useless, the key to making it work is the remember API.

Comment: Unbelievable. I'm learning kotlin+comose too. For first timer, it's confusing when your focus on understanding the fundamentals and instead, you keep jumping from blog to blog trying to resolve issues with the provided code.  Thank you for adding your own code -D.Y.won - and the explanation Madis-manni. Very helpful.